# Terraform error Bad substitution while running shell script

Tags: linux, bash, docker-compose, terraform

I'm executing shell script in terraform and getting Bad Substitution and getting below error:

module.bastion_ubu.aws_instance.ubuntu_bastion (remote-exec): /home/ubuntu/create.sh: 101: /home/ubuntu/create.sh: Bad substitution.

Code:

````
#!/bin/bash

tools_list="nginx/ldap/mongo/cloveplatformui"
tools_list1=`echo $tools_list | sed 's/ //g'`
tools_list2=`echo $tools_list1 | sed 's/$/\//'`
tools_list3=`echo $tools_list2 | sed 's@/@.yml @g'`
tools_list4=`echo $tools_list2 | sed 's@/@.conf @g'`
#tools_list_array=($tools_list6)
#tools_conf_array=($tools_list8)

#echo $tools_list_array
sudo touch docker-compose.yml
sudo chmod -R 755 docker-compose.yml
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu docker-compose.yml
sudo echo '---' >> docker-compose.yml
sudo echo 'version: "3.3"' >> docker-compose.yml
sudo echo 'services:' >> docker-compose.yml

# Print array values in one line
echo "Print all elements in a single line"
for val in "${tools_list3[@]}\" ; do
sudo cat $val >> docker-compose.yml
done```
````

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Can you also include your Terraform code? If that's template then it's possible that you need to escape the `${}` construct you have in your shell script.

Comment: `tools_list3` isn't an array, so `${tools_list3[@]}` doesn't make sense. Also, the escaped double-quote right after that will cause big trouble. Also, is this really getting executed by bash, or is it running under plain `sh` (which is actually dash in recent versions of Ubuntu).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Executing in bash.
As your suggestion I have changed from ${tools_list3[@]} to  $((tools_list3)).
And getiing below error.
```module.bastion_ubu.aws_instance.ubuntu_bastion (remote-exec): /home/ubuntu/createStack.sh: 113: /home/ubuntu/createStack.sh: Illegal number: nginx.yml ldap.yml cloveplatformui.yml.```

Any mistake is there...
Please suggest me

Comment: @Cyrus, Thanks checked the code and did some modifications.

Still getting a error.
```module.bastion_ubu.aws_instance.ubuntu_bastion (remote-exec): /home/ubuntu/createStack.sh: 113: /home/ubuntu/createStack.sh: Illegal number: nginx.yml ldap.yml cloveplatformui.yml```

Comment: `$(( ))` tells the shell to evaluate the contents as an arithmetic expression -- not what you want at all. Depending on exactly what the tools list contains, you might be able to use `for val in $tools_list3; do` and let word-splitting break the value up, but if any items contain whitespace (or anything in `$IFS`) or `*` or `?` or `[`, you can get results ranging from just wrong to bizarre to disastrous. There are probably better ways. But the rest of the script doesn't really make sense either; I'd try running it with `set -x` at the beginning so you can get a better idea what it's doing.

Comment: @GordonDavisson After changing the "for val in $tools_list3; do" getting below error.

```module.bastion_ubu.aws_instance.ubuntu_bastion (remote-exec): + [[ nginx.yml == jenkins_blueocean.yml ]]```

Comment: That's not an error, that's output from `set -x` showing what's being compared. Does terraform treat any output to stderr as a fatal error? If so, redirect error output to someplace else by putting something like `exec 2>/tmp/create.log` (before the `set -x`), so it'll send that output to /tmp/create.log instead of having it confuse terraform.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I have added like below.

```#!/bin/bash

exec 2>/tmp/create.log
set -x

tools_list=" nginx/ldap/mongo/cloveplatformui/GraphQlServerAPI/jenkins_blueocean/sonar/nexus/gitlab/ldap_phpadmin " ```

is there any mistake please check

Comment: @venkatesh Is it supposed to set `tools_list` to the string "nginx/...", or is it supposed to *run* that, and store its output in `tools_list`? If the latter, use `tools_list=$(nginx/.../ldap_phpadmin)`. Also, I recommend running the script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net], and fixing what it points out.

Comment: @GordonDavisson As suggested I have like below:
exec 2>/tmp/create.log 
set -x

Getting same output:
```+ [[ nginx.yml == jenkins_blueocean.yml ]]
/home/ubuntu/createStack.sh: 117: /home/ubuntu/createStack.sh: [[: not found
+ [[ nginx.yml == mongo.yml ]]
/home/ubuntu/createStack.sh: 126: /home/ubuntu/createStack.sh: [[: not found
+ [[ nginx.yml == sonar.yml ]]```

Comment: @GordonDavisson I have checked in Shellcheck.net but no luck...

Getting same error

Comment: That error ("`[[: not found`") looks like the script is running under dash instead of bash. Are you running the script with `sh scriptname`? If so, that ignores the shebang and will run it under /bin/sh (or whatever's first in your `PATH`), and in [recent versions of Ubuntu that's dash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).